# Web services security using spring aop

Tags: java, spring, web-services, aop, spring-ws

I try to create web service using Spring framework and want to secure my services. When I read spring documentation I came across Wss4jSecurityInterceptor which provides security. Can I use the Wss4jSecurityInterceptor in a declarative way using Spring AOP so that the application developer can be concentrate only on business logic.